# Calculate field with previous value in dplyr by group

Tags: r, function, dplyr, iteration

I want to use dplyr to calculate a field using it's previous value. A for loop would do the job but I want to calculate by different groups of *st*. I understand mutate (lag or ave) can't use an unitialized field.

```
df <- data.frame(st = rep(c('a','b', 'c'), each = 5),
                     z = rep(c(10,14,12), each = 5),
                     day = rep(1:5, 3),
                     GAI = rep(0:4, 3),
                     surfT = sample(1:15))
df %>%
   group_by(st) %>%
   mutate(soilT = lag(soilT, order_by = day) + (surfT - lag(soilT,
            order_by = day))*0.24*exp(-z*0.017)*exp(-0.15*GAI))
```

or

```
df %>%
  group_by(st) %>%
  mutate(soilT = ave(soilT, c(st), FUN=function(x) c(0, soilT + (surfT - soilT)))
         *0.24*exp(-z*0.017)*exp(-0.15*GAI))
```

how can a simple for loop be caculated in dplyr by group of *st*:

```
  df$soilT <- 0
  for (i in 2:dim(df)[1]){
    df$soilT[i]=df$soilT[i-1] + (df$surfT[i] - df$soilT[i-1])
                                 *0.24*exp(-z[i]*0.017)*exp(-0.15*GAI[i])
  }
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. It seems that your for loop simplifies to `soilT[i] = surfT[i]`? The only exception is `soilT[1]`, which is always 0.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add the last part of the second term trying to be more concise and soilT[i-1] won't cancel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `accumulate` from `purrr` to get the output of previous row as an input to current row.

```
library(dplyr)

result <- df %>%
           group_by(st) %>%
           mutate(soilT = purrr::accumulate(2:n(), 
            ~.x + (surfT[.y] - .x)*0.24*exp(-z[.y]*0.017)*exp(-0.15*GAI[.y]), 
            .init = 0))
```

Comment: That won't work since soilT is uninitialized in the right part: Error : Problem with `mutate()` input `soilT`.
x object 'soilT' not found
i Input `soilT` is `lag(soilT, default = first(soilT)) + (surfT - lag(soilT, default = first(soilT)))`.

Comment: @Marc-OlivierGasser I agree with ekoam, `soilT[i-1]` would cancel each other out and only `surfT` remains. Can you check if my updated answer is what you need?

Comment: sorry I modified the function, where the second term has a last part and soilT[i-1] won't cancel out.

Comment: @Marc-OlivierGasser We can use `accumulate`. Check updated answer.

Comment: It seems to work, many thanks. I will look into purrr to see how to handle different cases where we want to use data mobile mean from past 5 days with weights,etc. For bigger datasets, would purrr be usable with datatable ?

Comment: Yes, you can use `purrr` functions with `data.table`. There is also `Reduce` function in base R which can be used similarly.